# "At least make this" vs "make this at least" - which is grammatical?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Which one of the following sentence is grammatically correct?

- Can we at least make this predictable?
- Can we make this at least predictable?

What is the grammar rule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a matter of grammar, but of semantics; that is, **meaning**.

The two sentences have slightly different meanings. Consider:

> Can we at least make this predictable?
>   `Can we make this predictable, even if we cannot do anything more?`
>   *`Alternatively:`* `Can we make this predictable, even if no one else can?`
>   Can we make this at least predictable?
>   `Can we make this predictable, even if we cannot make it something more than predictable?`
>   Can we make at least this predictable?
>   `Can we make this thing predictable, even if we cannot make anything else predictable?`
>   *Can at least we make this predictable?
>   *`(This option may not be very natural and might only be used with contrastive emphasis)`*

The above are not hard and fast, and also depend a lot on context and intonation. But the point is that shifting the 'at least' does change the meaning, however slightly.

Comment: Your fourth example doesn't sound right at all (whatever the meaning is expected to be). But the other ones are right.

Comment: @Mitch, yes I noticed that after I read it aloud to myself. :)

Comment: It works if you mean: *Can we, if no-one else, make this predictable?*

Comment: I don't think much of your definition of *semantics*.  As a matter of syntactic interpretation (that is, grammar), your first two sentences are distinct.  But if one sentence cannot be true (or false) without the other having the same truth-value, they are semantically the same.

Comment: @TimLymington In this venue I mean semantics in the linguistic sense, not the sense used in formal logic.

Comment: _At least_ is a quantifier and thus binds a focus, which is normally stressed. Quantifiers can generally occur either immediately before their bound focus phrase, or immediately before a constituent containing it. That's why the first example can have either **this** or **predictable** stressed and is therefore ambiguous, but not the second one.

Answer (score 4):

They are both grammatical. They mean slightly different things.

> Can we at least make the cat predictable?

This requests that if nothing else is achieved, the cat needs to be predictable.

> Can we make the cat at least predictable?

This requests that if the cat can be nothing else, it should be predictable.

Comment: These are trick questions, cats cannot be made predictable.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Me in particular.

Answer (score 0):

They are both valid in different situations. It depends exactly what you are trying to say, and what "this" refers to.

Comment: "Schroedingers Cat" commenting on a question about making cats predictable... !

Comment: Then I would suspect "Can we make it at least predictable" seems like a better sentence to my mind. I wish I could explain why, but I think it is something about the scope of the task.